# "Match but exclude" in amazon Redshift's REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: regex, posix, amazon-redshift, regex-lookarounds

I have been reading *a lot* of questions and info on REGEX but haven't found anything conclusive yet.

I am using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` in amazon redshift which according to the documentation uses the regex flavour POSIX. My understanding is that it is fairly basic and *cannot* do look aheads.

Is there any way to match a pattern but exclude characters that come at the beginning or the end ?

I am trying to parse a `user_agent` field in our database and this would really help.

### Example

Sample string 1 : `'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone...'`
Match hoped: `iPhone`

Sample string 2: `'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; ...'`
Match hoped: `Windows NT 10.0`.

I am trying to match what is between the first parenthesis and the following semi-colon (`iPhone`) but **exclude** the parenthesis and semi-colon from the match.

For the moment I am using `'\\(.*;'` but it's fairly basic and feel like it could easily return a wrong match.

I understand I could couple the returning match with redshift's `substring` but doing so results in fairly messy and unpredictable code. I am wondering if it would be possible to have a regex match that return just the string needed.

I know other flavours of regex that can use look aheads could solve this but they are not available in redshift as far as I know.

Any help or pointers would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested SPLIT_PART does the job:

```
SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(user_agent, '(', 2), ';', 1)
```

It does exactly what you're looking for, and an empty return can be treated as a NULL value if you want to:

```
NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(user_agent, '(', 2), ';', 1), '')
```